# c# Form freez after try to socket connect

Tags: c#, sockets

i created form appliction, and tried to make chat with socket i have problem when its execute line "acc = sck.Accept();" the form freez and cant press any button whats is in Form, basicly, freez! What im foing wrong? Doing by tutorial

```
static Socket sck;
    static Socket acc;
    static int port = 9000;
    static IPAddress ip;
    static Thread rec;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            rec = new Thread(recV);

            ip = IPAddress.Parse(GetIp());
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));
            sck.Listen(0);
            acc = sck.Accept();

            /*while (true)
            {
                byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TEST");
                acc.Send(sdata, 0, sdata.Length, 0);
            }*/
        }
```

Comment: The Socket.Accept() method is a blocking method.  It is designed to stop the thread that called it until the connection is made, and that includes the UI thread if that is where you called it from.  Use and async method or call the Socket.Accept method from a new Task or Thread, and it will not freeze like this.

Comment: You should call that method in a different thread. That method would block the thread. If you run it on the UI thread it blocks the UI thread so that's why you can't press any buttons etc.

Comment: There are only two options, use another thread or try async.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AcceptAsync` like this:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    rec = new Thread(recV);

    ip = IPAddress.Parse(GetIp());
    sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));
    sck.Listen(0);
    acc = await sck.AcceptAsync();
    //This will block here, let the UI thread continue and then resume when a connection is accepted

    /*while (true)
    {
        byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TEST");
        acc.Send(sdata, 0, sdata.Length, 0);
    }*/
}
```

Note that the method is now `async` and I'm using `await in front of the`AcceptAsync` call.

If you want your Send/Receive methods to also free the UI, look into their corresponding `Async` method.